# Granting privileges for Importing data to AWS Lightsail MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-lightsail

I have a MySQL database running on *AWS Lightsail*. I'm trying to import data into MySQL using MySQL Workbench, but see following error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 20: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

Upon trying to grant access to `dbmasteruser` using following command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Super_Priv='Y' WHERE user='dbmasteruser' AND host='%';
```

I see following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ERROR (RDS): SUPER PRIVILEGE CANNOT BE GRANTED OR MAINTAINED' in 'field list'
```

Using following command:

```
mysql> GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO dbmasteruser@'%';
```

I see following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dbmasteruser'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I seems I stuck in a loop: I cannot import data and `dbmasteruser` doesn't have privileges neither to import nor to grant certain privileges to import.

I also see `rdsadmin` user with `DBA` privileges, but no idea where to get password in *Lightsail* for this user.

Comment: I'm under the same circumstances. Feels like we are left without proper access credentials and the database is useless like that.

Comment: I experience the same issues, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: I exported an existing database with MySql Workbench (this was an older MySQL version) and tried to import it into my AWS Lightsail Database - wich didn't work.

The reason were some operations in the mysql dump, which are not allowed for the Lightsail user. I just commented out the mentioned lines and the import worked as expected (in your case it's line 20).

For me I needed to comment out the following statements:

```sql
-- All lines that begin with
SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN...
SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED...
```